# Terms of the use for the API

Tags: support

What are the terms of use for the API? Are there any restrictions in terms of how I can use it, except for access limitations?

Answer (score 2):

I can only imagine that everything released under the API is subject to the site's Terms of Use. See the footer of the page for that information.

Comment: I don't see a relevant link in the footer: About doesn't mention ToU or link to one; nor does faq; cc-wiki and attribution is for the user contributed content.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am mistaken, there is no codified terms of use ATM.

That said:

1) All the data is CC-Wiki+Attribute

2) [This](https://stackapps.com/questions/405/acceptable-use-of-copyrighted-logos-names) says you may use the logo to ID where the data is coming from but your app must not have the same look and feel or use any of the other trademarks.

3) With an API key you get 10K calls per 24hr, and I believe there is rate limiting although I don't recall the SO crew publicly stating what it is.