# Acceptable Use of Copyrighted Logos/Names?

Tags: discussion

## Are any/some/all of the following considered acceptable use of the site names and logos?

I know that there is no "official policy" yet regarding this, but I figured I would show some examples of what I would like to use in [my application](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-desktop-notification-app) and try to get some feedback from Kevin, Joel/Jeff, etc before I proceed to invest time and effort on something that I will get sued for :-P

Perhaps we can also use this question to discuss the acceptable use policy for API apps, since there seems to be bits and pieces of information scattered among a few questions and comments on both stackapps and meta -- but no definitive source.

## 1. Small icons with site name to show question origin

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiXa0.png]

## 2. Drop down using site names to make a selection

[image]

## 3. Drop down using small icons and site names to make a selection

[image]

Comment: Nice sketches :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I completed a draft of the **"Guidelines for the use of Stack Exchange Network Logos and Names"** this past weekend.

### Update

---

Here are the relevant portions from the final draft of the logo usage guidelines. Pending any last-minute changes, this should pretty much cover "fair use" of the logos in your applications.

#### Design of Your Product

**Do:**

- **Do** design your product with unique branding and logos.
- **Do** feel free  to use our names or logos for the purpose of labeling our sites within your product, as long as use of such logos could not be confused with the branding or endorsement of the product itself.

**Do not:**

- **Do not** copy the look and feel of our products.
- **Do not** include elements of our network that are not user-contributed content (i.e. no copyright material).
- **Do not** use our name, logo, or service to promote or allow fraudulent, abusive, or otherwise illegal activities.

Comment: That may not be an option for some, who have had the logos deeply embedded in their app since day one. For them, it would be mountains of work to remove the logo from their app only to turn around and add them again should some fair use policy be brought in.

Comment: How about saying all **new** apps refrain from using the logo. 'Cuz I know I'm not the only one who has this problem.

Comment: @George: http://stackapps.com/questions/95/are-there-any-high-resolution-scalable-svg-icons-or-images-available/115#115 - they have already said you can't use their logos - all 'new' apps as a policy simply wouldn't work: what about an app I am developing now and have a key for? Is that a new app, or does that already exist?

Comment: whoops.  I'm using the logos on StackTop to tell the user what site they are currently browsing.  Would that be allowed under the guidelines or not?

Comment: @Matt: Do what I did - email the team.

Comment: @Matt S.: Check my latest update/edit and see if that answers your question.

Comment: @Robert, thank you for posting this excerpt.  Will the full draft be available somewhere in the near future?

Comment: Very near, yes. The final copy will be linked to these sites very soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Please someone resolve this!**

This has been hanging over my head long enough.

As you all know, my apps make extensive use of the logos. And although I have been careful about how I used them, I wouldn't mind official approval.

Currently I use the logos for:

- Presenting a list of API-compatible sites to a user
- In a status panel beside a user's name and score

*I would also like to know why my post with the SVG versions of the logos was deleted.*

Comment: Your SVG post was deleted because a third party distributing high quality versions of our trademark'd logos is definitely not kosher.

Comment: @Kevin: But the StackOverflow team wasn't offering any logos. One could argue that *somebody* had to do it. (Well not *had to*, but the need was there.)

Comment: Could we please clarify the use of the logos? **Please?**

Comment: look to Robert's answer for updates.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that.